# Consultar 3 tablas a través del modelo de una cuarta tabla en laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

soy nuevo en el mundo de laravel, 
necesito hacer una consulta en 3 tablas relacionadas para imprimir el resultado por el método show

(Persona: documento pk,...)
(Contrato: [id pk,  area fk, cargo fk documento fk])
(Area: [id pk, nombre])
(Cargo: [id pk, descripcion])

pude crear una relacion de  hasOne  entre persona y contrato, pero necesito ver los detalles de área y cargo, para poder verlos  por el controlador  en el método show

---

este es mi modelo persona (me permite ver los datos de la persona y detalles de contrato, pero muesta las foraneas de cargo y area)

```
protected $table='persona';

    public function contrato()
{
        return $this->hasOne(Contrato::class,'documento');
}
```

---

este es mi modelo de contrato(me permite ver el detalle de contrato  por 'dd' pero me muestra como 'null' los campos de área y cargo)

```
  protected $table='contratos';

    public function persona(){
        return $this-> belongsTo(Persona::class);
    }

    public function cargo(){
        return $this-> hasOne(Cargo::class,'id');
    }

    public function area(){
        return $this-> hasOne(Area::class,'id');
    }
}


Perdon por responder tan tarde,

public function index()
    {
          $contrato= Contrato::with('area','cargo')->get();
        return view('/contrato',compact('contrato'));
    }
```

este es el metodo índex que uso para ver los datos del contrato

---

este es el modelo que me permite ver el detalle de contrato por 'dd' pero me muestra como 'null' los campos de área y cargo

```
class Contrato extends Model
{
    protected $table='contratos';

    public function persona(){
        return $this-> belongsTo(Persona::class); //relación con tabla persona  
    }

    public function cargo(){
        return $this-> hasOne(Cargo::class,'id');
    }

    public function area(){
        return $this-> hasOne(Area::class,'id');
    }
}
```

---

Este es el controlador de persona, este me deja ver los detalles de persona y contrato por la vista show,

```
public function show(Persona $persona)
    {
        return view('personal.show',[
            'persona'=>$persona
        ]);

    }
```

---

modelo Persona

```
class Persona extends Model
```

{

```
protected $table='persona';

    public function contrato()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Contrato::class,'documento');
}
```

Comment: quiero mostrar los detalles  de la persona, el contrato, el nombre el área y del cargo.  pero estos dos últimos son dos tablas relacionadas con la tabla contrato

Comment: Muéstranos cómo haces esto: "modelo de contrato (me permite ver el detalle de contrato por 'dd' pero me muestra como 'null' los campos de área y cargo)". También de qué modelo partes para hacer la consulta y lo que tengas en el método `show` del controlador.

Comment: exacto.  eso es lo que quiero   pero no se como formular la consulta en laravel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partimos de tener los siguientes modelos:

- Persona
- Area
- Cargo
- Contrato

Ahora basándonos en las tablas que muestras al inicio entonces cada uno de los modelos debería tener el siguiente contenido:

Modelo Persona:

```
class Persona extends Model
{
    public function contrato()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Contrato::class);
    }
}
```

Modelo Area

```
class Area extends Model
{
    public function contrato()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Contrato::class);
    }
}
```

Modelo Cargo:

```
class Cargo extends Model
{
    public function contrato()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Contrato::class);
    }
}
```

Modelo Contrato:

```
class Contrato extends Model
{
    public function area()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Area::class);
    }

    public function cargo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Cargo::class);
    }

    public function persona()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Persona::class);
    }
}
```

Ahora mediante la técnica de *eager loading* vamos a hacer una carga ambiciosa de Persona con todos sus contratos relacionados

De esta forma:

```
Persona::with('contrato')->findOrFail(1); //el 1 será el id de la persona por la cual deseas filtrar
```

Sin embargo obtendrás un resultado similar a este:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "usuarioUno",
    "email": "mail1",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
        "contrato": {
        "id": 1,
        "persona_id": 1,
        "area_id": 1,
        "cargo_id": 3,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
    }
}
```

Sin embargo solo estamos obteniendo las llaves foráneas de:

- área
- cargo

Entonces necesitamos obtener esa relación entre contrato y las 3 entidades anteriores para recuperar sus valores.

Si analizamos, vemos que `Persona` si tiene una relación directa con `Contrato` pero no así con las entidades: `Area` y `Cargo` por lo cual tendremos que usar esta sintaxis:

```
Persona::with(['contrato.area', 'contrato.cargo'])->findOrFail(1);
```

Con una salida similar a esto:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "usuarioUno",
    "email": "mail1",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
        "contrato": {
        "id": 1,
        "persona_id": 1,
        "area_id": 1,
        "cargo_id": 3,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
            "area": {
            "id": 1,
            "nombre": "area 1",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
            },
            "cargo": {
            "id": 3,
            "descripcion": "cargo 3",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
            }
        }
}
```

- [Aquí puedes leer mas sobre eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)